# How to execute perl command in current Bash process

Tags: perl

Today, I write a bash script to open and close a special python virtual envionment. You want to close the virtual environment, you must in the same bash process with command **deactivate**, so you can use command ~source~ to execute you bash script.(Preface)

### Perl question

Here is my perl script

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl 
BEGIN{
    $\="";
}
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature "switch";
use Cwd qw(chdir cwd);
no warnings "experimental::smartmatch";
our $path = $ENV{"PATH"};

if($path =~ /sspider\/bin/){
    print "Scrapy virtual environment opened already\n";
    print "Do you want to close it? [y/n]:";
    chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
    given($answer){
        when(/[yY\n]/){
            my @path = split(/:/, $path);
            my $scrapy_path;
            for (@path){
                if(/sspider/){
                    $scrapy_path = $_;
                }
            };
            print $ENV{PWD}, "\n";
            chdir("$scrapy_path") or die "Can't goto scrapy bin directory";
            print $ENV{PWD}, "\n";
            system("deactivate");
            print "Closed successfully\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Because when I execute the perl script, it is running in a new process, so it can't close the virtual environment.

So, I want to know how to solve it.(**Execute a command in the current bash process in perl script**.

### Process

[Perl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVxLO.png)

Comment: In bash: `exec myscript.pl` to replace the bash process with it?

Comment: The solution is to *stop* *using* *virutalenv*.  The entire approach is fatally flawed and absurd.  But....all it really does is set a few environment variables like PYTHONPATH and PATH and VIRTUALENV.  Read through the activate script and see what it's doing...it's not much.  Set your PYTHONHOME as needed and move one.

Comment: @Shawn I can't understand your meaning, when I use `exec` command, the bash process exit at the moment.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I use the **venv** moudle, and I write this script just for fun.-:)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to run Perl code as part of the current bash process. Bash cannot execute Perl code by its own so it needs to run the Perl interpreter - which is separate program and thus will run as a new process.

What might be done though is to create some file by the Perl program which then gets sourced by the shell - thus running the shell-instructions in this created file in the context of the current shell.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I thought that I can with some command go to the parent process, so funny.-:)

Comment: Re "*I thought that I can with some command go to the parent process*",  You *can* find the parent process. But then what? How do you tell an already running bash to execute a command? That's the impossible part.

Comment: @ikegami I know it's impossible, so I add "so funny" after that.

Comment: @zhou alias Re "*I know it's impossible*", I said it's NOT impossible. It's quite easy, in fact, to "go to" the parent process.

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, these day I can't login this website.Can you tell me how to "go to" the parent process with perl?

Comment: The parent process is obtained using `getppid`

Comment: @ikegami Think you, I find the usage of this function, the main question is how to pass these command to parent process.

Comment: We've already covered that's impossible. You can obviously ask the shell to execute commands, but the shell takes commands from its stdin, and you have no way of feeding to its stdin. And even if you could, the shell is not currently taking input because it's waiting for a program to end.